# select one input from multiple HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I select in CSS, one input from more inputs with same type?

```
<input type="submit" value="send">
<input type="submit" value="reset">
```

I want to edit only input with value reset

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[value="reset"] {
    background-color: red;
    border:none;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="send">
<input type="submit" value="reset">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using same style in many element you can create `.css` file and add there.Or else you can do like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="reset" style='background-color:green;'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input[type="submit"]:last-of-type`

Comment: good but he didn't mention need for last button .he specified value name.